# Navigation look like slide show

Tags: swift, iphone, xml, xcode

**My Problem :** I have to edit a swift code but I face a problem where the navigation look like slide show in new iphone devices ONLY, but when I use old iphone I don't face this issue.

**Images of problem :**

**Old Iphone :**

[image]

**New Iphone :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `modalPresentationStyle` of the ViewController you're presenting to .fullScreen.

```
viewControllerToBePresented.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Comment: I change it from story board, https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen-a9c7c9679f48

Comment: Both are different methods for the same thing.